# Is there a way to disable namespaces inside a complexType in a soap request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap

I have 2 Java Webservices talking to each other via SOAP, both are using Spring Boot 3.0.7 on JDK17. Now i updated one of the services to Spring Boot 3.1.2 and they can't communicate with each other anymore.

The exception thrown is:
`org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element`

After some digging using LoggingInterceptors I found out that the two Spring Versions are marshalling/unmarshalling the soap messages in different ways. Here examples for method calls of updateWorkflowConfiguration :
Spring 3.0.7:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:updateWorkflowConfiguration xmlns:ns2="http://some.package.structure/">
            <workflowConfiguration>
                <accountId>0</accountId>
                <comment>asd</comment>
                <dateRange>0</dateRange>
                <id>1</id>
                <systemId>0</systemId>
            </workflowConfiguration>
        </ns2:updateWorkflowConfiguration>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Spring 3.1.2:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:updateWorkflowConfiguration xmlns:ns2="http://some.package.structure/">
            <workflowConfiguration>
                <ns2:accountId>0</ns2:accountId>
                <ns2:comment>asd</ns2:comment>
                <ns2:dateRange>0</ns2:dateRange>
                <ns2:id>1</ns2:id>
                <ns2:systemId>0</ns2:systemId>
            </workflowConfiguration>
        </ns2:updateWorkflowConfiguration>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The only difference is the (not) referenced namespace `ns2` in the bean of type `workflowConfiguration`. The Bean is as simple as its gets with no annotations whatsoever which would influence the outcome of the SOAP Message. 
The CXF dependencies are in both cases the same:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

These two services are just the tip of the iceberg as there are close to 60 projects with dependencies on one or the other service. So a simultaneous update to the new spring version is not possible.
Until now i found nothing to define how the namespace is added to an element. Is there some possibility to configure or switch between the "old" (pre 3.1.2) and the new way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting really on my nerves, i checked which version of Spring Boot was working and which wasn't. I discovered that its not only the 3.1.x branch which is suffering from this but also 3.0.x from 3.0.8 onward.
Reviewing the upgraded dependencies in this release and their respective updates the breaking change seems to be related to [this bug](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1731) ans should be fixed in [this MR](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/pull/1752) without release as of now. So for now downgrading the org.glassfish.jaxb dependencies to 4.0.2 solves the problem.